# How to populate custom attribute while creating product with Bulk API ? 'asych/bulk/v1/products'?

Tags: magento2.4, bulk-products-update, async

I want to populate  custom attribute while creating create product.
I have created below plugin which is working fine while saving product using **REST Bulk API** `v1/products`.

But it's not working while we are running this bulk product save **API** `asynch/bulk/v1/products`.

File location are given below"

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="name-integrations" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Is anyone know the class name of bulk product save?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bulk product updates don’t use the `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` when saving product data. You can see in the queue consumer `Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\Backend\Consumer::execute()` that it is calling `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action::updateAttributes()`.

You didn’t specify what your plugin does, but maybe you can create an observer on the event `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` which gets emitted during that call chain I mentioned above.

Comment: I want populate custom attribute while create product using bulk API